# Как при переводе времени вперед не дать сработать просроченным Alarms?

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, уведомления

Пишу приложение, которое выводит уведомления по расписанию, используя Alarm, BroadcastReceiver и Notification. В обычных условиях все работает.

Если пользователь захочет перевести время вперед, хотелось бы, чтобы он не увидел те уведомления, которые устарели. С этим у меня проблема.

Для тестирования заданы 5 будильников-уведомлений с интервалом в 1 минуту. Если я перевожу время на моем смартфоне, скажем, на час вперед, эти будильники срабатывают все разом и только потом запускается мой BroadcastReceiver, который их отменяет. 
Если я перевожу время на пару минут вперед, то срабатывают 2 устаревших будильника, а остальные отменяются.

То есть, как мне кажется, проблема в том, что сначала событие android.intent.action.SET_TIME получают системные службы, запускающие просроченные будильники, а уж потом запускается мой BroadcastReceiver.

Хотелось бы, чтобы порядок был обратным. Была попытка установить наивысший приоритет для моего BroadcastReceiver, но это не помогло.

Вот мой BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class CancelNotificationsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationPlanner.cancelAlarmNotifications(context);
    NotificationPlanner.clearNotificationList(context);
}
```

}

Так он прописан в манифесте:

```
<receiver android:name=".notifications.CreateNotificationListReceiver">
        <intent-filter
            android:priority = "999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Проверено, что методы

```
NotificationPlanner.cancelAlarmNotifications(context);
    NotificationPlanner.clearNotificationList(context);
```

отменяют все будильники с уведомлениями.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Версия SDK - 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению это никак не исправить, т.к. система имеет больший приоритет. Она так запрограммирована, что будильники, которые просрочили своё время имеют наибольший приоритет и их нужно выполнить незамедлительно. Я бы вам не советовал быть настолько педантичным, т.к. даже довольно популярные приложения не учитывают такие факторы, поэтому можно часто заметить, что при переводе времени во многих приложения могу срабатывать аналогичные таймеры и т.п. Но раз уж вам сильно этого хочется, то можете сделать свою проверку "перевода времени" в AlarmManager-е и при каждом вызове будильника удостовериться, что перевода времени не было и будильник сработал как нужно, но поверьте, это ещё тот костыль.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Вы вывели меня из тупика. Теперь я собираюсь отказаться от реакции на SET_TIME и ограничиться только сменой даты и перезагрузкой. Этого, как мне кажется, достаточно для адекватной работы приложения, ведь уведомления по задумке выводятся раз в сутки.